# ValueListenableBuilder does not redraw custom widgets

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a Todo App only using ValueNotifiers but when trying to update a todo state as done the ListView does not update the children

My ValueListenableBuilder code:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: todoNotifier,
        builder: (_, value, __) {
          return ListView.separated(
            itemCount: value.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              return TodoTile(todo: value[index]);
            }),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const Divider(
                thickness: 2,
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

The code for the custom tile:

```
ListTile(
      title: Text(todo.text),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: todo.isDone
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.done_all,
                color: Colors.blue,
              )
            : const Icon(Icons.done_all),
        onPressed: () => todoNotifier.toggleDoneTodo(todo),
      ),
    );
```

The code for TodoNotifier class:

```
class TodoNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<Todo>> {
  TodoNotifier()
      : super(<Todo>[
          Todo(text: 'sample1', isDone: false),
          Todo(text: 'sample2', isDone: false),
          Todo(text: 'sample3', isDone: true),
          Todo(text: 'sample4', isDone: false),
          Todo(text: 'sample5', isDone: false),
        ]);

  void addTodo(String text) {
    value.add(Todo(text: text, isDone: false));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteTodo(Todo todo) {
    value.remove(todo);
  }

  void toggleDoneTodo(Todo todo) {
    todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
    print(todo.toString());
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

the only solution found implies that I would not create a custom TodoTile
the code for the solution would be:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: todoNotifier,
        builder: (_, value, __) {
          return ListView.separated(
            itemCount: value.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(value[index].text),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: value[index].isDone
                      ? const Icon(
                          Icons.done_all,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                      : const Icon(Icons.done_all),
                  onPressed: () => todoNotifier.toggleDoneTodo(value[index]),
                ),
              );
            }),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const Divider(
                thickness: 2,
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

I suppose that the problem is happening because Flutter is not repainting the custom widgets

Comment: can you provide a gist/dartPad link

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/EmanuelLamba/29144167ce8ab9a5cf7a90e2864a9dad

Comment: it works just fine: basically you have two `final todoNotifier = ...` - make sure there is only one notifier

Comment: @pskink I used two notifiers, one more inside the `TodoTile` so I don't pass the notifier through every widgets. But now I realise that you are right, I'll use a service locator so I instantiate the notifier only once. I'll be back with an answer

Comment: use  `todoNotifier ` like a global variable

Comment: check this: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue using the global variable. The issue was that I was trying to use 2 different instances of the ValueNotifier thinking that calling one instance will update both. The solutions found would be: using global variable, using a service locator or updating the notifier to be a singleton. Thanks guys for the help.